# Accessing Bitnami Kafka in K8s Cluster from Host?

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, kubernetes-helm

After running:

```
helm repo add bitnami https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami
helm install my-release bitnami/kafka
```

I then got pods:

```
$kubectl get pods
NAME                     READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
my-release-kafka-0       1/1     Running   2          24m
my-release-zookeeper-0   1/1     Running   0          24m
```

I attempted to access the Kafka running in my cluster to list topics:

```
$kafka-topics --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --list
[2022-05-15 22:31:05,190] WARN [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
```

It failed. I then tried to forward port 9092 from the guest to the host:

```
$kubectl port-forward my-release-kafka-0 9092:9092
Forwarding from 127.0.0.1:9092 -> 9092
Forwarding from [::1]:9092 -> 9092
```

In another tab, I tried and failed again:

```
$kafka-topics --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --list
[2022-05-15 22:31:35,288] WARN [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Error connecting to node my-release-kafka-0.my-release-kafka-headless.default.svc.cluster.local:9092 (id: 0 rack: null) (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
java.net.UnknownHostException: my-release-kafka-0.my-release-kafka-headless.default.svc.cluster.local: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
    at java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:929)
```

What is the meaning of:

```
Error connecting to node my-release-kafka-0.my-release-kafka-headless.default.svc.cluster.local:9092
```

and how can I address this problem, i.e. so that I can access my cluster's Kafka from my local, the host?

Answer (score 2):

It returns the pod DNS name because that's the `advertised.listeners` setting on the broker.

I'd recommend using Strimzi Operator rather than Bitnami Helm Charts, and reading the documentation on it about accessing the brokers using LoadBalancer or Ingress resources

Or decipher what you need from the Traffic Exposure parameters - https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/kafka/#traffic-exposure-parameters + https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/kafka/#accessing-kafka-brokers-from-outside-the-cluster

Answer (score 1):

In order to access locally your Kafka broker deployed in Kubernetes cluster with a port-forward, you need to add **127.0.0.1:9092** as **Kafka advertised listener**.

In Bitnami Kafka Helm Chart, the configuration is done with `{{ .Values.advertisedListeners }}`. The value will be injected in the Kafka `StatefulSet` container with the env variable `KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS`

As an example here is an extract of a Kafka `StatefulSet` YAML manifest with a such configuration :

```
    - name: KAFKA_CFG_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP
      value: CLIENT:PLAINTEXT
    - name: KAFKA_CFG_LISTENERS
      value: CLIENT://:9092
    - name: KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS
      value: CLIENT://127.0.0.1:9092
```

Comment: This will only work if you're using one broker, right? The values setting will go to all brokers. This is why you should create an headless Service + NodePort, or Ingress instead, for actually using a Kafka cluster